# Посчитать кол-во определенного слова в тексте

Tags: c#, строки

Допустим, есть `.txt` документ с текстом:

```
"У меня есть собака. Моя собака самая лучшая."
```

Нужно узнать кол-во слов `"собака"` (их может быть больше 50 штук).

Comment: А что вы сами пытались сделать? А то домашки у нас за учеников не решают тут.

Answer (score 1):

```
string search = "Прицепом прицеплен прицеп";
string pattern = $"\\b{Regex.Escape(search)}\\b";
int count = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Matches(source).Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "У меня есть собака. Моя собака самая лучшая."; 
Regex.Matches(s, "собака").Count // выведет 2
```

Comment: А если искать нужно не слово "Собака" а скажем слово "прицеп" в предложении Прицепом прицеплен прицеп, что ваш метод вернёт ?

Comment: 2 или 3 если использовать с .lower()

Comment: нет, вы суть не уловили, неверный метод у вас. Искать нужно целевое слово, а не вхождение !

Answer (score 0):

```
"У меня есть собака. Cобака моя самая лучшая надсобака из всех подсобак."
                                              .Split(',','.',' ',';')
                                              .Select(s => s.Trim().ToLower())
                                              .Count(s => s == "собака".ToLower())
```